Question about edge ‎(vertex) coloring number
$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Definitions:
1: In graph theory, a proper edge coloring of a graph is an assignment of "colors" to the edges of the graph so that no two incident edges have the same color. Similarly, a vertex coloring assigns a color to each edge so that no two adjacent vertices are of the same color.‎
‎‎‎The smallest number of colors needed in a (proper) edge coloring of a graph $G$ is the chromatic index‎, ‎or edge chromatic number‎, ‎$ \chi^{\prime}(G)= k $‎.
2: Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite simple graph‎. ‎The Sombor index $\SO(G)$ of $G$ is defined as $\SO(G)=\sum_{uv\in E}\sqrt{d_u^{2}+d_v^{2}}$‎, ‎where $d_u$ is the degree of vertex $u$ in $G$‎.
‎Questions:
‎

1: ‎Can the upper bound value be obtained according to the ‎edge‎ (vertex)‎ coloring number‏?


2: ‎Does the value of the Sombor index also increase with the increase of the edge‎ (vertex) coloring number‏? Meaning, if ‎$‎G‎$‎ and ‎$‎H‎$‎ are two graphs such ‎that‎‎ $ \chi^{\prime}(G)= k‎_{1}‎ $ and ‎$\chi^{\prime}(H)= k‎_{2}‎ $ and ‎$ k_1 < k_2$‎, is ‎$\SO(G) < \SO(H)‎$‎?


I don't understand the first question. As for the second, what about $G=C_4$ and $H=C_3$?
